# dns server is not used after some time

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns

I have a set of host names that could be resolved only with a specific remote dns server `A`, so I have several DNS servers in network card TCP protocol settings.

This works for some time. I do not know exactly, but that could be hours or even days. After that time host names from DNS just stop resolving. I can not open them in web browser, ping etc. However `nslookup` can resolve these host names.

I solve this problem by "updating" dns server configuration. I just change order of DNS servers, I do not think that order plays any role but it just resets internal state of windows DNS system.

Sometimes connection to DNS server `A` is lost, so I suspect it is a cause for such behaviour, i.e. DNS server is not accessible then it is not queried any more.

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation and workaround was written in [this article](http://blog.johnruiz.com/2011/12/windows-does-not-always-honor-dns-order.html) based on Microsoft [Knowledgebase 320760](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320760/en-us) which seems to be applicable to Windows XP and Windows 7.

Microsoft:

*This behavior occurs because the Windows XP DNS Client service (Dnscache) follows a 
certain algorithm when it decides the order in which it uses the DNS servers configured in 
the TCP/IP properties. If the DNS server list is reprioritized, the Windows XP DNS Client 
service resets the server priority at periodic intervals. By default, the server 
priorities are reset every 15 minutes.*

Workaround description:

To work around this behavior, modify the registry so that the DNS server that is configured first is tried first on each query. Follow these steps, and then quit Registry Editor:

1. Click `Start`, click `Run`, type `regedit`, and then click `OK`.
2. Locate and then click the following key in the registry:

   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters**
3. On the `Edit` menu, point to `New`, and then click **REG_DWORD**.
4. Type **ServerPriorityTimeLimit**, and then press `ENTER`.
5. On the `Edit` menu, click `Modify`.
6. Type 0, and then click `OK`.

When you set **ServerPriorityTimeLimit** to 0 (zero), the server priorities are reset before the DNS Client service decides which DNS server to use. You must restart Windows XP for these changes to take affect. Any other value used in this field will cause the default behavior.

Note: In the `ServerPriorityTimeLimit` registry setting, only values of 0 change the default behavior. All other values cause the default behavior.

Comment: Not clear from `If the DNS server list is reprioritized, the Windows XP DNS Client service resets the server priority at periodic intervals. By default, the server priorities are reset every 15 minutes.` how long does these resets are done, i.e. I reprioritize DNS servers how many times will priorities be reset every 15 minutes. Hope it is clear what I want to say :)